# Have overlap behavior of background events the same as normal events?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Looking at this example: http://jsbin.com/mezudexiti/1/edit?js,output
we can see the background events overlap in a way making then difficult to distinguish, while the normal events are nicely cascaded. Is there a way to have the background events the same?

I could just style normal events as transparent, but I want to have another 'layer' on top where I can put events that aren't affected by the background ones overlap.

Comment: When in `javascript` context you probably shouldn't call *calendar entries* events - quite confusing. Also no idea what the actual question is.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting a custom isBG attribute, and checking for it/adjusting the width in the eventAfterRender callback.
Code here: http://jsbin.com/kisiquxojo/1/edit?js,output